# Temperature different of adapter since Mountain Lion (maybe only rMBP related)

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, magsafe

Since I've got ML (Mountain Lion) installed, I've got the feeling that my adapter (Magsafe-2) is not getting as hot as before?

Since this is my first Macbook, I really wasn't familiar with the adapter's temperature. My rMBP's adapter seemed to get so extensively hot, that I could actually smell it when holding it somewhat close to my face and could almost not keep it for longer period of time in my hand.

Though, since I've got ML installed, it seems my adapter is cooler through charging my Macbook then before. Still, ofcourse, it gets hot, but definitely not as hot as before.

I wondered - though not getting anything worthy out of knowing - if you guys are experiencing this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambidex,

The power usage in the rMBP is MUCH better under Mountain Lion than it was under Lion.  This causes less wear and tear on the Magsafe.  Depending on the amount of charge needed it's quite possible the device will work harder to power up from 20% battery than from 80%.

T

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting, I a have been running a non-Retina i7 for over a year, Lion OSX, and have found that CPU and GPU get drastically throttled as MagSafe-1 gets hotter and hotter. Nothing unusual I guess but I didn't expect it to impact the performance of the machine.
I may just upgrade to Mountain Lion, hopefully that will fix the throttling!

Comment: Not an answer...

Comment: I think you forgot that when you start you can't provide the comment (which will of course be appropriate in the case) on this very board. Don't be harsh on the newcomer because I think and you will agree I belive the experience @JB_1 shared is up to the topic.